# Where is speciffication about eclipse project upgrade operation?

Tags: eclipse

I have a project in my eclipse workspace. After eclipse is started and workspace checked popups a window ["Project Upgrade"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RoUz.jpg) which says that one of mine projects is

> ... created with older release of Eclipse and/or related plugins.

And does propose me to upgrade my project.

I want to know what exactly does "project upgrade", which files it touches and what exact changes will provide to them. Is it documented somewhere? I didn't find any useful information in [eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org).

I'm using eclipse helios. But I want to know if is it somewhere some place with change log of "project structure" through eclipse versions.

Comment: I don't think there is such a list. Was the project created by an older Eclipse? My guess is the old style plugin.xml - so what does the plugin.xml look like?

Comment: @greg-449 my project is it not plugin. I don't have in my project folder the "plugin.xml" file. And I don't know if this project was created by an older eclipse version. Can it be configured so by an old plugin?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what would cause this for a non-plugin project.